# pytest - sepearate fixture logic from the tests

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have several packages I want to to write `pytest` tests for. All the packages should use same fixture logic, so I want to have the common test logic (fixtures) to sit in some common path and each package test should reside in its own path.

```
Repository 1:
=============
/path/to/PackageA/test_A.py
/path/to/PackageB/test_B.py

Repository 2:
=============
/different_path/to/Common/conftest.py
```

The problem is that when I run `pytest` on `test_A.py` or `test_B.py`, `pytest` doesn't find fixtures defined in `conftest.py`.
Tried to play with `--confcutdir` option, but with no luck...

The only scenario that is working for me is running `pytest` from `/different_path/to/Common/`, while setting `pytest.ini` `testpath = /path/to/PackageA/` (BTW running `pytest /path/to/PackageA/` didn't work).

Comment: I think what you could try is to import fixtures defined in `/different_path/to/Common/conftest.py` to `/path/to/PackageA/conftest.py` and `/path/to/PackageB/conftest.py`. To do that you have to either add this `Common` directory into your PYTHONPATH or you could import using full path as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to that problem is to transform `Common` into a pytest plugin. If you already have a `setup.py` for that `Common` project, it is just a matter of adding this to your `setup` call:

```
# the following makes a plugin available to pytest
entry_points = {
    'pytest11': [
        'common = Common.plugin',
    ]
},
```

You will have to rename `Common/conftest.py` to `plugin.py` though (or something else other than `conftest.py`), as py.test treats that file name specially.

If you don't have a `setup.py` for `Common`, then you can make py.test use it as a plugin by adding `addopts = -p Common.plugin` to `PackageA/pytest.ini` and `PackageB/pytest.ini`.